# Is localstorage shared between windows session

Tags: local-storage

I'm not able to find anything related to localStorage and if it shared between multiple user session on the same computer!?

Anyone can answer this question ?

Comment: The data stored in `localStorage` persists until explicitly deleted. Changes made to the `locaStorage` are saved and available for all current and future visits to the site. You can access `localStorage` within a session and without a session, but it'll be the same for all the sessions, and thus for all the users. I am not sure but, maybe you're looking for `sessionStorage`.

Comment: nope, i wanna know if someone else connect on my machine but with their windows account, do they have the same localstorage than me ?